# Mysql timestamp field in table makes SELECT query slow

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using Inno db table (called test) with 300k rows with the following fields:

```
id(int), sn(int), ts(timestamp), note(text), error_id(int)
```

Indexes are `id`, `sn` and `ts`.

`SELECT ts FROM test LIMIT 0, 100` takes in avarege of 0.3-0.35 second,
when everything else, like `SELECT id FROM test LIMIT 0,100` takes 0.04 seconds.

Only when selecting `*` or `ts`, it takes a lot of time for SELECT to finish.
Do you know why this happens (10x more time to exec SELECT by ts than others? )

real table:

```
CREATE TABLE `production_list_log` (<br/>
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br/>
  `sn` int(11) NOT NULL,<br/>
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'ts - timestamp when ordercode arrived to this station\n',<br/>
  `note` text COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci,<br/>
  `error_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,<br/>
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),<br/>
  KEY `fk_change_product_id` (`product_id`),<br/>
  KEY `sn_ts_added_kalup` (`sn`,`ts`) USING BTREE,<br/>
  CONSTRAINT `fk_change_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE<br/>
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=297567 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can we see the table info? Do you have any indexes set up?

Comment: Are you doing any WHERE or ORDER BY stuff? The fields you select shouldn't make that big of a difference on speed by themselves, unless you or the server has a fairly slow internet connection.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: - Added table info
- No WHERE just simple: 
SELECT id FROM production_list_log
LIMIT 0,100 
- The question is: Why 10x more time to exec select by ts than other fields in db